# Dell Studio 1747 Video Driver

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, radeon

I have an old Dell Studio 1747 with an integrated ATI video card. Linux identifies the device as (Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650/5165]), but it can't locate any proprietary driver, so the open-source driver doesn't have hardware acceleration at all! :(
I tried to install amdgpu-pro, amd-catalyst, fglrx packages, but with no luck. All that I found are obsolete drivers for Ubuntu 14.x.

sudo xrandr --listproviders returns:
**Providers: number : 1 Provider 0: id: 0x55 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650 @ pci:0000:02:00.0**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no proprietary driver for old AMD cards, ...nothing we can do about it. For hadware acceleration, check out the output of  `vainfo`. There should be some support for h264.

Comment: Could you provide info from `xrandr --listproviders` inside your question, please?

Comment: sudo xrandr --listproviders returns:

Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x55 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650 @ pci:0000:02:00.0

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-15-7), you are under obsolete world, i'm afraid.

Comment: But in that link, they list the (ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 5000 Series). so is there any hope?

Comment: it is a obsolete driver for a [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) version of ubuntu

Comment: But the laptop is 2009, how come the driver is obsolete? on Windows, the driver is working perfectly with full acceleration :(